# shopware 6: how can I get a price rule ID at updating productrepository

Tags: shopware

I have a question about programmatically updating a product via the Shopware 6 `ProductRepository`. I will update actionprices for my product.
But then rule Id is a required field. But how can I get this **Rule ID** field?

```
    $price = [[
        'linked' => false,
        'net' => (float)$netPrice,
        'gross' => (float)$grossPrice,
        'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,

    ]];

    $prices = [
        [
            'quantityStart' => 1,
            'ruleId' => '???', // How can I get this???
            'quantityEnd' => 10,
            'price' => [
                [
                    'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,
                    'gross' => $actionGrossPrice,
                    'net' => $actionNetPrice,,
                    'linked' => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

So how can I get this rule ID field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not post the full code, especially the portion where you call the update function. I am assuming, that you are trying to set the "advanced pricing" of a product.

Before doing something programmatically, it might be a good idea to check how it's done manually.

In the admin panel (Shopware v6.4.3.0), creating advanced price rules also needs a rule id:

[image: Screenshot of Shopware asking for the rule ID to create an advanced price]

This refers to a rule created before unter Settings -> Shop -> Rule Builder.

There are some rules created by default, for example "all customers":

[image: Rule all customers]

You can pick the rule ID from the URL when clicking that rule and use this in your code.

[image: pick the rule id]

This might be fine if you write a plugin for one specific shop. But the rule would differ in other shops.

**In case you are writing a plugin for a broader audience**, I recommend to make the rule to be applied [configurable in the plugin configuration](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/use-plugin-configuration).

You could of course also search programmatically for a rule "All customers" - but it might have been deleted by the shop owner.